# How to call div form to PHP mail function？

Tags: php, wordpress

I got a problem need help.

I got a custom order form at wordpress and want to put the total price to the function.php.

Here is the total price using script to calculator any show at "0", so I want to get this number (Total Price) to the function.php $message .= "Total - $totalPrice\n";

```
<div name="totalPrice" id="totalPrice" class="totalPrice">0</div>
```

Here is the code at function.php

```
function submit_form() {
if(isset($_POST['submit_form'])) {
    
    $str = date('Ymd') . str_pad(mt_rand(1, 99999), 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    //echo $str;

    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $deliverydate = $_POST['deliverydate'];
    $deliverytime = $_POST['deliverytime'];
    $payment = $_POST['payment'];
    $address1 = $_POST['address1'];
    $address2 = $_POST['address2'];

    $item_ids = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['submit_form']));
    $itemid = $_POST['itemid'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $item_names = [];        
    $items = "Item - Qty\n";

    foreach($item_ids as $item) {            
        foreach($item as $k => $i) {
            $item_names[$k] = $i;
        }
    }

    foreach($itemid as $k => $itm) {            
        if(isset($item_names[$itm])) {
            $items .= $item_names[$itm] .' - '. $qty[$k]."\n"; 
        }           
    }
    

    
    $message = "";
    $message .= "Order No  - $str\n";
    $message .= "Name  - $gender $name\n";
    $message .= "Phone  - $phone\n";
    $message .= "Email  - $email\n";
    $message .= "Delivery Date  - $deliverydate\n";
    $message .= "Delivery Time  - $deliverytime\n";
    $message .= "Address  - $address1 $address2\n";
    $message .= "Payment  - $payment\n";
    $message .= "-----------------------\n";
    $message .= $items;
    $message .= "-----------------------\n";
    $message .= "Total - $totalPrice\n";

    $admin_mail = 'email@gmail.com';
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "New Order";
    
        'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";*/

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: xxx@xxx.com '. "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To:'. $email . "\r\n";
        
    }

    $sent = mail($admin_mail, $subject, $message, $headers);
        if($sent) {
            //echo "sent <br>";
        }//message sent!
        else  {
            //echo "failed";
        }//message wasn't sent


    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        if($sent) {
            //echo "sent <br>";
        }//message sent!
        else  {
            //echo "failed";
        }//message wasn't sent
```

}
add_action( 'init', 'submit_form' );

Comment: `div` elements don't have a `name` attribute, and adding one nevertheless, still doesn't make them behave like form fields. If you want this value to be send with a normal form submission, then you need to stick it into an actual form field first.

Comment: (And that any user could _manipulate_ the value, if you let the client calculate & send it, is clear, I hope?)

Answer (score 1):

Div elements do not have a name attribute. You could use an hidden input for each prise instead, so you can pull the value out of it.

```
<input type="hidden" value="0"></input>
```

Dont forget to put the input in to an form element, so you can pull the value. It would look something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <div name="totalPrice" id="totalPrice" class="totalPrice">0</div>
   <input type="hidden" value="0"></input>
   <!-- Some other Code -->
   .
   .

</form>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, but this still can't work.